# Customising the Mailboxer gem - Rails 4 - Send message linked to a listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging, mailboxer

I have been trying to customise the Mailboxer gem to suit my purposes. There are some other SO posts which reference similar functionality but I wanted to ask this question as it is somewhat different.

I refactored my Messages Controller from this:

```
def new
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user])
end

def create
  recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
  conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
  flash[:success] = "Message has been sent!"
  redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
end
```

To:

```
def new
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user])
  @message = current_user.messages.new
  @listing = Listing.find_by(id: params[:listing])
end

def create
  @recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:user])
  conversation = current_user.send_message(@recipient, "Hello", "Subject").conversation
  flash[:notices] = ["Your message was successfully sent to the seller"]
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

I then also added to messages/new.html.erb:

```
Send a message to
<%= @user.email %>
<%= form_tag({controller: "messages", action: "create"}, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:listing, "#{@listing.id}") %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:user, "#{@user.id}") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Send Message', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This allows me to access the user object I am sending the message to as well as the listing id so the message can be linked to a listing.

Github repo: https://github.com/benhawker/rails_marketplace/tree/master/app

The user model includes: `acts_as_messageable`

I am not drawing any errors here, but after validating in the rails console the user that I was looking to send the message to has nil for `@user.mailbox.conversations`

If anyone who has tried to do the same thing with Mailboxer is able to explain where I am going wrong would really appreciate it.

```
conversation = current_user.send_message(@recipient, "Hello", "Subject").conversation
```

I am aware that this line is probably key - I don't fully understand the purpose of the `.conversation` after passing the arguments into the `send_message` method the Mailboxer gem provides.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post up my eventual solution to this. I ended up rolling my own messaging solution taking heavy inspiration from this excellent post on Medium https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1.

It is far from perfect and there is a significant amount of refactoring in the Inquiries Controller which needs to happen but it is functional and solves my original question.

Created an Inquiry Class with the following associations.

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: "User"
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy, validate: false

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes["message"].blank? }

  validates_presence_of :sender, :recipient, :listing
  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(inquiries.sender_id = ? AND inquiries.recipient_id =?) OR (inquiries.sender_id = ? AND inquiries.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

And then a message class associated with each inquiry.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :inquiry

  validates_presence_of :body, :inquiry_id, :user_id
end
```

Then created an InquiriesController

```
class InquiriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @inquiries = Inquiry.all
  end

  def new
    @sender = User.find_by(id: params[:sender])
    @recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient])
    @listing = Listing.find_by(id: params[:listing])

    @inquiry = current_user.inquiries.new
    @message = @inquiry.messages.build
  end

  def create
   @sender = User.find_by(id: params[:sender_id])
   @recipient = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
   @listing = Listing.find_by(id: params[:listing_id])
   if Inquiry.between(@sender,@recipient).present?
     @inquiry = Inquiry.between(@sender, @recipient).first
   else
     @inquiry = Inquiry.create!(inquiry_params)
     @inquiry.listing << Listing.find_by(id: params[:listing_id])
   end
   redirect_to inquiry_messages_path(@inquiry)
 end

 private
 def inquiry_params
   params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id, :listing_id)
 end
```

In my listings/show page I then pass through sender, recipient and listing id's to populate the inquiry object.

```
<%= link_to "Contact the Seller", inquiries_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id, listing_id: @listing.id), method: 'post' %>
```

Which then allowed in inquiries/index:

```
<% @inquiries.each do |inquiry| %>
  <% if inquiry.sender_id == current_user.id || inquiry.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
    <% if inquiry.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <% recipient = User.find(inquiry.recipient_id) %>
    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(inquiry.sender_id) %>
    <% end %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to "Messages with #{recipient.email} about #{inquiry.listing.title}", inquiry_messages_path(inquiry)%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: cant make it to work.. Could you please provide the other relevant files of the messaging system like messages controller, inquiries/new.html.erb, routes file etc

Comment: This is the repo where I implemented this - https://github.com/benhawker/rails_marketplace

Comment: Thanks a lot.. By the way gorails have a screencast on mailboxer which covers your question i think. Here is the link https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-messaging-between-users